# getting multiple post id wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am making a voting system for my theme

It is working fine in single.php

But when i keep it in index.php it only considers the id of first post and rest don't work

I think its not dealing with multiple post id

Here is the full code

Setting a cookie, calling Ajax action with jQuery

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */ 
(function($) {
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

$("#vote").not(".disabled").click(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    el.html('<span id="loader"></span>');
    var nonce = $("input#voting_nonce").val();
    var data = {
        action: 'add_votes_options',
        nonce: nonce,
        postid: '<?php echo $post->ID; ?>',
        ip: '<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>'            
    };
    $.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data,
    function(response){
        if(response!="-1") {
            el.html("VOTED").unbind("click");
            if(response=="null") {
                alert("A vote has already been registered to this IP address.");
            } else {
                $("#votecounter").html(response);
                alert("Thanks for your vote.");
            }
            var cookie = getCookie("better_votes");
            if(!cookie) {
                var newcookie = "<?php echo $post->ID; ?>";
            } else {
                var newcookie = cookie + ",<?php echo $post->ID; ?>";
            }
            setCookie("better_votes", newcookie, 365);
        } else {
            alert("There was a problem registering your vote. Please try again later.");
        }
    });
    return false;
}); 
})(jQuery);
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

This is what I put in my functions.php to register actions

```
 add_action("wp_ajax_add_votes_options", "add_votes_options");
 add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_add_votes_options", "add_votes_options");
 function add_votes_options() {
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'voting_nonce'))
    return;

$postid = $_POST['postid'];
$ip = $_POST['ip'];

$voter_ips = get_post_meta($postid, "voter_ips", true);
if(!empty($voter_ips) && in_array($ip, $voter_ips)) {
    echo "null";
    die(0);
} else {
    $voter_ips[] = $ip;
    update_post_meta($postid, "voter_ips", $voter_ips);
}   

$current_votes = get_post_meta($postid, "votes", true);
$new_votes = intval($current_votes) + 1;
update_post_meta($postid, "votes", $new_votes);
$return = $new_votes>1 ? $new_votes." votes" : $new_votes." vote";
echo $return;
die(0);
 }
```

this is how I call my vote button and count button

```
  <?php
 // This will display "0 votes" and increase as votes are added
$votes = get_post_meta($post->ID, "votes", true);
$votes = !empty($votes) ? $votes : "0";
if($votes == 1) $plural = ""; else $plural = "s";
 echo '<div id="votecounter">'.$votes.' vote'.$plural.'</div>';
 ?>

 <?php
  // This will display the vote button and disable it if a cookie has already
 // been set. We also add the security nonce here. 
 $hasvoted = $_COOKIE['better_votes'];
 $hasvoted = explode(",", $hasvoted);
 if(in_array($post->ID, $hasvoted)) {
$vtext = "VOTED";
$class = ' class="disabled"';
 } else {
$vtext = "VOTE";
$class = "";
}
?>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="vote"<?php echo $class; ?>><?php echo $vtext; ?></a>
 <?php if(function_exists('wp_nonce_field')) wp_nonce_field('voting_nonce', 'voting_nonce'); ?>
```

Comment: The main part is jQuery code postid.

Comment: can you remove the last part of code and instead post your `get_post_meta` function and what is sent via this ajax call: `$.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, (...)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for a beginning, you shouldn't have the same id for your button over and over again, so change this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="vote"<?php echo $class; ?>><?php echo $vtext; ?></a>
```

To this:

```
<?php 
if(in_array($post->ID, $hasvoted)) {
    $vtext = "VOTED";
    $class = ' disabled';
} else {
    $vtext = "VOTE";
    $class = "";
}
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="vote-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="vote-btn<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $vtext; ?></a>
```

This will result in id attribute of each vote button in the form of "vote-{post id}". And since I guess you still want to address all of your buttons in some way, you can now use the `.vote-btn` selector.

The problem with your JavaScript is that you pass the ID of the post to the script directly. This is fine, when you have only one post on the page, but when you have multiple posts, you have to either print your code multiple times, or get the post ID dynamically.

I prefer the second option, here's how your JS code should change in order to get that working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */ 
(function($) {
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

$(".vote-btn").not(".disabled").click(function() {
    var el = $(this),
        nonce = $("input#voting_nonce", el.parent()).val(),
        id = el.attr('id').replace(/vote-/, ''); // get the Post ID

    el.html('<span id="loader"></span>');
    var data = {
        action: 'add_votes_options',
        nonce: nonce,
        postid: id,
        ip: '<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>'            
    };
    $.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data,
    function(response){
        if(response!="-1") {
            el.html("VOTED").unbind("click");
            if(response=="null") {
                alert("A vote has already been registered to this IP address.");
            } else {
                $("#votecounter").html(response);
                alert("Thanks for your vote.");
            }
            var cookie = getCookie("better_votes");
            if(!cookie) {
                var newcookie = id;
            } else {
                var newcookie = cookie + "," + id;
            }
            setCookie("better_votes", newcookie, 365);
        } else {
            alert("There was a problem registering your vote. Please try again later.");
        }
    });
    return false;
}); 
})(jQuery);
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

So, in the above code, we get the ID of the post that the user is voting from, by replacing "vote-" with an empty string(so only the ID remains). Note also the following line:

```
nonce = $("input#voting_nonce", el.parent()).val(),
```

In this line, I assume that the nonce input as well as the button have the same parent(although you should be able to use the same nonce for all posts). You can also take your nonce one step further, by changing the code that generates it to:

```
<?php if(function_exists('wp_nonce_field')) wp_nonce_field('voting_nonce-' . $post->ID, 'voting_nonce'); ?>
```

And change your `add_votes_options` function to:

```
$postid = $_POST['postid'];
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'voting_nonce-' . $postid ) )
    return;
```

This will bind each nonce to the ID of the post, that the nonce is for.

I think that's pretty much your problem. Please try my code and tell me if there are problems with it(if it's a JS error, please add message from the error console in FireBug, or WebKit's inspector).

---

PP: Just saw this:

> Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

My answer was backed-up by my experience with WordPress and jQuery - and I earn my living by working mainly with WordPress(less jQuery, but I use it relatively often as well). Hope this will be enough :)

Comment: Hey it worked like a charm but after click votes aren't increased

Comment: They are not increased via Ajax .they are increased after the page is refreshed

Comment: So, then the problem is in the response of the function. Can you do a `console.log( response );` at the top of the function that handles your AJAX callback?

Comment: Oops I don't know how to do this as am a newbie in all this things

Comment: Simply place the line of code from my previous comment after this line in your script: `function(response){`. Then Refresh the page and after clicking on a vote button look in your browser's console - if you're using Chrome or Safari, you already have one(press F12 and go to the Console tab) - if you're using Firefox, you can install [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/bg/firefox/addon/firebug/) addon and press F12 and again go to the console tab. Paste the output here. Also if you have an accessible URL where I can see the site - that will work as well(you'll still need to add the code).

Comment: Sorry for that. I fixed it

Comment: Change `$("#votecounter").html(response);` to `$("#votecounter", el).html(response);` - note this is still not a good fix, since you have the id "votecounter" repeating multiple times. Instead I'd recommend that you change the id to class on the votecounter div. You'll also need to update your CSS and JS to reflect that as well though.

Comment: Oh, sorry try this: `$("#votecounter", el.closest('article')).html(response);`

Comment: Thankk you very much for ur quick response .every thing is working fine now.@

Comment: But according to SO I can reward you bounty only after 13hours from now

Comment: Can U check there .they are not working when a new set of post are fetched by infinite scroll .what JavaScript should I callback at blog.newgags.com

Comment: Change this line: `$(".vote-btn").not(".disabled").click(function() {` to this: `$("body").on('click', '.vote-btn:not(.disabled)', function() {` . This will bind even to newly created buttons.

Comment: So in order for this to work, replace all `href="javascript:void(0)"` with `href="#"`. Also remove this: ` onclick="addClass('vote', 'yellow')"`(this says that `addClass` is undefined and breaks the JS). Lastly add the following line: `$(document).ready(function(){` before `$("body").on('click', ...` and this line: `})` before `})(jQuery);` (this is the same part where you handle the vote button clicks).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21682/discussion-between-nikola-ivanov-nikolov-and-vaibhav-bhanushali)

Comment: click never gets diabled after i click vote only get disable after refresh bcoz of cookies